# Error message when trying to run ChromeDriver for codeception

Tags: codeception

I am wanting to use Webdriver in my codeception acceptance tests and am getting errors.  I see I have to have the chromedriver running and tried running it from the  command window and it seems to run fine using: chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub.  I want to use the RunProcess extension so added this to my acceptance.suite.yml file:

```html
actor: AcceptanceTester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codecption\Extensions\RunProcess:
            - chromedriver
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost/flightserve/'
            browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptance
step_decorators: ~
```

and I get this error message and do not know hoe it needs to be defined.
Class `Codecption\Extensions\RunProcess` is not defined. Autoload it or include into '_bootstrap.php' file of 'tests' directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

- You have some typos with the extension path. It should be `Codeception\Extension\RunProcess`. So singular 'Extension' and 'Codeception' spelt correctly.
- You may still hit issues because the chromedriver hasn't properly started up before the test suite tries to run. You could try introducing a short delay using `sleep`:

```
- Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
    0: chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub
    sleep: 5
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typos jonnykates